# Does Server Internet Bandwidth affect internet client download speeds

Tags: ipv4, tcp, bandwidth, network

I'm studying computer networking and have a good understanding of tcp/ip how data travel across the internet and etc.  But one thing I keep wondering is that does a Server's Internet Bandwidth affect internet clients' download speeds.  If so which portion of it, the server's internet download or upload speed.

If 10 computer was to download a file from a server at 10 Mbps each (50Mbps total) and the server only has a internet connection of 30Mbps download and 15Mbps upload wouldn't the server be slowing down those internet client's download because the server can only push out 30 Downs and 15 Ups and the clients demand is 50 downs.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, Yes.

If the server has an upload capacity of 100Mbps then regardless of the clients connecting, it can only service those clients up to 100Mbps. So if 10 clients connect, that allows (in an idea world, which isn't always realistic) 10Mbps per client. Even if those clients each had 1Gbps WAN connections, the server can only provide downloads at it's own maximum capacity.